# Write script which sorts files by Month from LastModificationDate property

Tags: powershell

Write script which sorts files by Month from LastModificationDate property:

- Script creates “Month” directory for each file and moves it there
- Input argument is path to set of files (mandatory, accept pipeline)
- Script returns nothing

This function is working only on current directory. Need it to take a folder parameter. How can I change the script?

```
function Get-FileMonth {

    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [string]$Folder
    )
        $Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -File
        Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -File | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime.Month}`
        | New-Item -Name {$_.LastWriteTime.Month} -ItemType Directory
        ForEach ($File in $Files)
            {
            Copy-Item $File -Destination "$($File.LastWriteTime.Month)"
            }
    }
```

Comment: You have correctly added the required code to _accept_ a parameter as a folder; you're not _using_ that parameter in your code. Once you have the folder, what do you want to _do_ with it?

Comment: If I execute this function with parameter (except the current directory). It creates folders but didn't copy the file, because it is looking in the current directory, not in the directory which I provide in parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would perform the tasks you are asking:

```
function Format-Files ($folder) {

    #Get all files in the folder
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -File

    foreach($file in $files){
        #Create a new path using the LastWriteTime.Month property
        $fullPath = (Join-Path -Path $folder -ChildPath $file.LastWriteTime.Month)

        if (!(Test-Path $fullPath)){
            #The directory needs to be created
            New-Item -Name $file.LastWriteTime.Month -Path $folder -ItemType Directory
        }

        #Copy the item to the new directory
        Copy-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $fullPath
    }    
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions or issues. You should use this like:

```
Format-Files("C:\Path\To\Directory")
```

Comment: With PowerShell, the parens aren't necessary, and if he wants to have the Common Parameters (e.g., -Verbose, -ErrorAction, etc.), he should use the `[CmdletBinding()]` and `param(...)` block as his original code shows.